# Add WordWrap functionality to ButtonGroup buttons in Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Currently `TButtonGroup` doesn't have a `WordWrap` property. I was looking a way to have that functionality but my search for examples was so far not yielding any results.

My question is how can I add a wordwrap function for the caption of the buttons in `TButtonGroup?` Can you give me an example or guide me in the right track? 
Your answer is much appreciated!
BTW I use delphi XE3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple wordwrap will already happen, which can be seen if you change the caption at runtime of by editing the DFM like this.

```
Items = <
  item
    Caption = 'Word'#13'Wrap'#13'3 Lines'
  end
  ...
```

But the default painting will not look to good with WordWrap.
You could implement `OnDrawButton`, but that would need to write a lot of code.
The fastest way will be to set `gboShowCaption` in `ButtonOptions` to false and implementing `OnAfterDrawButton` like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonGroup1AfterDrawButton(Sender: TObject; Index: Integer; Canvas: TCanvas; Rect: TRect; State: TButtonDrawState);
var
 s:String;
begin
   InFlateRect(Rect,-4,-4);
   s := TButtonGroup(Sender).Items[Index].Caption;
   Canvas.TextRect(Rect,s,[tfWordBreak,tfCenter]);
end;
```

Comment: +1, for nice and simple (I was just post a sample using the `OnDrawButton` event, but your solution is more simple).  Just a note you can improve your code setting the value of Canvas.Brush.Style to `bsclear` when the custom styles are active and also calculating the vert. center of the text.

Comment: @RRUZ thanks, I just wanted to show where to hook, there are a lot of things which could/should be considered/improved ...

Comment: @bummi Awesome! It can't be simpler than this! and I used RRUZ input to maket it work with my styles. Thank you very much!!